# How to gain an intuition of the affine function's definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Here is the definition of Affine Functions according to Stephan Boyd (EE263 Stanford)  :
[image: Affine Boyd]

1- I believe linearity is more restrictive property of a function than being affine since it requires $f(0) = 0.$
I wonder, how is it the case that by imposing a constraint, namely  $\alpha + \beta = 1$, we achieve a less restrictive property?

2- How can we get an intuitive feeling of the concept of affinity via this definition?

Thanks

Comment: The restriction is there precisely because that prevents you from setting $\alpha = \beta = 0$ to obtain $f(\mathbf{0}) = f(0\cdot \mathbf{x} + 0 \cdot \mathbf{y}) = \mathbf{0}$ by definition. So using that "restriction" you allow more functions to fit the definition.

Comment: @molarmass Why this kind of restriction : $\alpha + \beta = 0$ ? We could have explicitly omitted the case where both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ equal 0...Or we could have used something like $\alpha \times \beta  = 1$

Comment: To address 1.: A linear function satisfies$$f(\alpha x + \beta y) = \alpha f(x) + \beta f(y)$$for _all_ $\alpha$ and $\beta$. By assuming $\alpha + \beta = 1$, you're not constraining $f$ itself, you're restricting _the set of conditions $f$ must satisfy_. That is, you get a _larger class of functions_ because you've _cut away fewer functions_ from the set of all functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's use another definition of an affine function.

> A function ${f}\colon \mathbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is called *affine* if and only if $$f(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}$$ for some $\mathbf{A} \in \Bbb R^{m \times n}$ and $\mathbf{b} \in \Bbb R^m$.

Let $f\colon \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ be an affine function and $\alpha,\beta \in \Bbb R$. Then
\begin{align*}
f(\alpha \cdot \mathbf{x} + \beta \cdot \mathbf{y}) &= \mathbf{A}(\alpha  \mathbf{x} + \beta \mathbf{y}) + \mathbf{b}\\&=\alpha \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} + \beta\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{b}\\
&\\
\alpha\cdot f(\mathbf{x}) + \beta\cdot f(\mathbf{y}) &= \alpha(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{b}) + \beta(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{b})\\
&=\alpha\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\alpha\mathbf{b} + \beta\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}+\beta\mathbf{b}\\
&=\alpha\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+ \beta\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}+(\alpha+\beta)\mathbf{b}
\end{align*}

So for affine functions to we require in general that $\alpha+\beta = 1$ for the relation $f(\alpha\mathbf{x}+\beta\mathbf{y}) = \alpha f(\mathbf{x}) + \beta f(\mathbf{y})$ to hold. In other words, these definitions are equivalent as long as $\alpha + \beta = 1$.

Comment: Thanks. This is in fact the answer of the question in the homework I asked of. I've already solved it similar to your way. Actually I'm looking for an intuition of affinity

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator What exactly do you mean by “intuition of affinity”?

Comment: A graphical representation or an application of it. I think people who defined such things had a problem to address. I don't think of it as only a manipulation of symbols

Answer (score 5):

This is a nice question. My answer lies more in the abstract side. In a nutshell, *affine* maps are for affine spaces the exact counterpart of *linear* maps for vector spaces. This point of view requires the introduction of the concept of "affine space".

**Reference** [Gallier's notes on affine geometry](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/papers/gallier/geomath2.pdf), which I strongly recommend on this subject.

In the following, let $\mathbb{K}$ denote a scalar field (usually $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$).

**Definition** A *affine space* is a triple $(A, V,+)$ where $A$ is a set, $V$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and $+\colon A\times V\to A$ satisfies the following axioms (analogous to the axioms of [Group action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action))

1. For any $p\in A$, one has $p+\vec 0 =p$.
2. For any $p, q\in A$ there exists a unique vector $\vec v\in V$ such that $p+\vec v=q$. This vector is denoted by $\vec v=q-p$.
3. For any $\vec v, \vec w\in V$, and for any $p\in A$, one has $(p+\vec v)+\vec w=p+(\vec v+\vec w).$ This is the same as to require that, for any three points $p_1, p_2, q\in A$, one has $p_1-p_2=(p_1-q)+(q-p_2).$

The elements of $A$ are called *points*, those of $V$ are called *vectors*. Any vector space is an affine space, and conversely, fixing an arbitrary point $o\in A$ and identifying it with the null vector $\vec 0$, one can endow $A$ with the same vector space structure of $V$. So that's why the two concepts are often confused.

In a vector space, one has the internal composition law of *linear combination*. In an affine space, linear combinations make no sense a priori. But one can define a notion of *weighted sum* (or *barycentric combination*, or also *affine combination*) as follows.

Let $p_0\ldots p_n\in A$ be points and let $w_0\ldots w_n\in \mathbb{K}$ (*masses* or *charges*) be such that $w_0+\ldots +w_n=1$. Then there exists a unique point $q$ such that, for whatever choice of $o\in A$,
$$\tag{1}
\sum_{j=0}^n w_j(p_j-o) = q-o.$$ One thus defines $q=\sum_{j=0}^n w_jp_j$.

*Proof*. One needs to check that (1) is covariant with respect to the change of origin, that is, that if one considers another origin $o'$ the equation (1) retains the same form. This is a consequence of property 3. and uses in an essential way the fact that the weights sum up to $1$. One has for the left hand side of (1) 
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n w_j (p_j-o)=\sum_{j=0}^n w_j(p_j-o')+\sum_{j=0}^n w_j(o-o')=\sum_{j=0}^n w_j(p_j-o')+(o-o'),$$
and the right hand side 
$$
q-o=q-o'+(o'-o), $$
so a change of origin produces the same change in both sides of equation (1). Therefore 
$$\sum_{j=0}^n w_j(p_j-o')=q-o', $$ as claimed. $\square$

One can carry the analogy between vector spaces and affine space a step further. In vector spaces, the natural maps to consider are *linear maps*, which commute with linear combinations. Similarly, in affine spaces the natural maps to consider are *affine maps*, which commute with weighted sums of points. This is exactly the kind of maps introduced by the textbook's definition of the OP.

Comment: Thanks. This is more on the advanced side. I should study your answer carefully when I have time

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator: Try to read the linked notes, or skim through them. I found them very useful when I was studying these things.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of two variables $\alpha$, $\beta$ satisfying the constraint $\alpha+\beta=1$ you can use one real variable $\tau$ (replacing the old $\beta$), and require that for all $x$, $y\in{\mathbb R}^n$ and all $\tau\in{\mathbb R}$ one has
$$f\bigl((1-\tau)x+\tau\>y\bigr)=(1-\tau) f(x)+\tau f(y)\ .$$
This is expressing the condition that the line $$\ell:\qquad \tau\mapsto(1-\tau) x+\tau \>y$$ connecting $x$ with $y$ is mapped onto the line $$\ell':\quad \tau\mapsto (1-\tau)f(x)+\tau\>f(y)$$ connecting $f(x)$ with $f(y)$ in a "linear" way, i.e., such that (signed) ratios between distances are preserved.

Comment: Vielen Dank Herr Professor. So here is what I understand: We have a line connecting two points in a n-dimensional space. An Affine Function is in fact the process of rotating and zooming in (or out) of that line with keeping in account the scalar factor by which we zoomed in (or out). Is this a correct picture?